# WinError 10054 in tutorial for APIs

Tags: python, xml, api, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do a course for fetching xml data with python but even though I follow the tutorial I keep getting a 10054 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    url = 'https://ehp.qld.gov.au/cgi-bin/air/xml.php?category=1&region=ALL'
    url_result = urlopen(url)
    raw_data = url_result.read()
    xml_soup = soup(raw_data, 'xml')    
    print(xml_soup)
```

This is the error when I try to run the code.

```
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-76e557f468e2> in <module>
      1 url = 'https://apps.des.qld.gov.au/air-quality/xml/feed.php?category=1&region=ALL'
----> 2 url_result = urlopen(url)
      3 raw_data = url_result.read()
      4 xml_soup = soup(raw_data, 'xml')
      5 print(xml_soup)


~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    927         try:
    928             if buffer is not None:
--> 929                 return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    930             else:
    931                 return self._sslobj.read(len)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: It means that the webhost has closed your connection. There could be many reasons, the most likely reason is that you need to spoof a user agent by supplying the header information as part of the request.

Comment: I am running this in jupyterlab and the tutorial I am following shows this exact code and setup working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not supply the user-agent info in your request. Even though you may be following a tutorial that had the code working, the website may have changed/updated.

I tried your code without a user-agent and I got the same error as you, but after spoofing a user-agent, the request worked.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
>>> url = 'https://ehp.qld.gov.au/cgi-bin/air/xml.php?category=1&region=ALL'
>>> req = Request(url)
>>> req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0')
>>> url_result = urlopen(req)
```